# Why is n log n dominated by n log^2 n?

Tags: big-o-notation

Does the rule of $n ^ a$ dominate $n ^ b$ if $a > b$ apply here as well?

My understanding is that $n \log n$ will be dominated by $n \log ^2 n$ because of $\log$ being raised to the power of $2$.

Comment: Can you please try and use [LaTeX/MathJax](https://cs.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex) to present formulas?

Answer (score 3):

**little-oh proof**

An equivalent but more straightforward question would be why $\lg n$ is *dominated by* $\lg^2 n$, that is why $\lg n \in o(\lg^2 n)$.

Then based on the definition of [little-oh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1364491/5230386) we need to show that for any choice of constant $ c > 0 $, we can find a constant $ n_0 $ such that the inequality $ \lg n < c \lg^2n $ holds for all $ n > n_0 $.

We prove that if we pick $ n_0 = \sqrt[c]{b} $ where $ b $ is the base of $ \lg $, then the definition above holds.

If $ n_0 = \sqrt[c]{b} $ then we have $ n > \sqrt[c]{b} $ or $ n > b^{\frac{1}{c}} $.  Now since $\lg n$ with a base $ b > 1 $ is an increasing function, then $ \lg n > \lg b^\frac{1}{c} $ or $ \lg n > \frac{1}{c} $.  If we multiply both sides by $ c > 0 $, we have $ c \lg n > 1 $.  Now we can multiply both sides by $ \lg n > 0$ (*Note that for $ \lg n > 0 $ to be true, we must have $ n_0 \geqslant 1 $ which leads to $ \sqrt[c]{b} \geqslant 1 $ or $ b^\frac{1}{c} \geqslant 1$ which results in $ \lg b^{\frac{1}{c}} \geqslant \lg 1 $ or $ \frac{1}{c} \geqslant 0 $ or $ c > 0 $; which is already guaranteed.*) to have
$$
 c \lg^2 n > \lg n .
$$
This is what we needed to show.

---

**Big-Oh proof sketch**

A slightly different but related question could be why $\lg n$ is *bounded above* by $\lg^2 n$, that is why $\lg n \in O(\lg^2 n)$.

The answer is that since $\lg n > 1$ for $n$ larger than the base of $\lg$, then if we raise $\lg n$ to any power greater than $1$ (including power of $2$), it will be larger than $\lg n$ itself.

(*We could rather argue that since we proved that $ \lg n \in o( \lg^2 n) $, it follows from $ o(f) \subset O(f) $ that $ \lg n \in O( \lg^2 n) $.*)

---

**Note**

So yes, the rule of $n^a > n^b$ if $a > b $ and $ n > 1 $ does apply here.  Note that this rule is equivalent to the statement that any exponential function with a base greater than $1$ is an *increasing function*.

Comment: (I seem to remember $f(n) \in o(g(n))$ for *dominated*, $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ for *bounded above*.)

Comment: Consider that $O(f) \supset o(f)$.

Comment: @greybeard I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $O(n \log n) = O(n \log ^2 n)$. This implies that for any function $f(n) \in O(n \log ^2 n)$, there exist a positive constant $k$ and a constant $n'$ such that $f(n) < k (n \log n)$ for all $n \geq n'$.

Take $f(n) = n \log ^2 n$. Clearly $f(n) \in O(n \log ^2 n)$.

So we have that there exists a value for $k$ and $n_0$ such that $n \log ^2 n < k (n \log n)$ for all $n \geq n'$.

Noting that $n \log ^2 n = n \log n \log n$, we arrive at a contradiction: whatever constant value we choose for $k$, there exists a value $n'$ such that $\log n > k$ for all $n \geq n'$.

---

In simpler terms, were $O(n \log n)$ to be the same as $O(n \log ^2 n)$, it would mean that $n \log ^2 n$ does not grow faster than some constant factor of $n \log n$. But this is obviously not correct as $n \log ^2 n$ grows at a rate of $\log n$ times $n \log n$ (and $\log n$ grows faster than a constant).